# Java client to Artemis cluster

Tags: java, high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have created 3 artemis master brokers on 3 machines. Each master has a slave node running on same machine. JGroup is used for this cluster. Now I want only one active server and remaining 2 as passive servers. When I connect to cluster, it seem load balancer sends my request to one of the servers ( May be round robin based?).

My configuration is

```
<configuration xmlns= .. >

<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
    <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>./data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>
    <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>
    <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616</connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616</acceptor>
    </acceptors>

    <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="Artemis-broadcast-group">
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-file_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
        <discovery-group name="Artemis-discovery-group">
            <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-file_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
        </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="Demo-Artemis-Cluster">
            <address></address>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <check-period>1000</check-period>
            <connection-ttl>5000</connection-ttl>
            <min-large-message-size>50000</min-large-message-size>
            <call-timeout>5000</call-timeout>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
            <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <confirmation-window-size>32000</confirmation-window-size>
            <call-failover-timeout>30000</call-failover-timeout>
            <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
            <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="Artemis-discovery-group" />
        </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>

    <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
    <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

    <security-settings>
        <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
        </security-setting>
    </security-settings>

    <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
        </address-setting>

        <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>

    <addresses>
        <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
        </address>
        <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
        </address>

    </addresses>

    <ha-policy>
        <replication>
            <master>
                <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
        </replication>
    </ha-policy>


</core>
```

Other 2 servers has similar config except ip in connector and acceptor.

test-jgroups-file is

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
<TCP recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:5M}"
    send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:5M}"
    max_bundle_size="64K"
    max_bundle_timeout="30"
    sock_conn_timeout="300"

    timer_type="new3"
    timer.min_threads="4"
    timer.max_threads="10"
    timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
    timer.queue_max_size="500"

    thread_pool.enabled="true"
    thread_pool.min_threads="2"
    thread_pool.max_threads="8"
    thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
    thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000"
    thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"

    oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
    oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1"
    oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
    oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
    oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"/>

    <TRACE/>

<JDBC_PING connection_url="connection_url" connection_username="username" connection_password="password" connection_driver="org.postgresql.Driver" />

<MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
        max_interval="30000"/>
<FD_SOCK/>
<FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
<BARRIER />
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
<UNICAST3 />
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
            max_bytes="4M"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
            view_bundling="true"/>
<MFC max_credits="2M"
    min_threshold="0.4"/>
<FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
<pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
<pbcast.FLUSH timeout="0"/>
```

On client side, I did this for both sender and receiver.

```
 jndiProp.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");

 jndiProp.put("connectionFactory.myConnectionFactory", "(tcp://10.168.100.41:61616,tcp://10.168.100.42:61616,tcp://10.168.100.43:61616)?ha=true");
```

I want one server to process all requests and other 2 in standby. OR Is it possible that sender use one connection/session to send message and receiver also use one line to read. In current scenerio, I have to check all 3 servers for messages on client side. I read it has something to do with `message-load-balancing` so I changed value from ON_DEMAND to STRICT. But seems that's not enough.
Any help regarding this? TIA

Comment: From an HA point of view, it doesn't make any sense to have the master and its slave on the same machine. With replication you can have two "passive" servers, but only one will be the designated slave and will receive data from master. Keep in mind that if you don't use the `ha-policy.replication.[master|slave].group-name` property, then a slave server could connect to any live master without a slave. Also note that with just one master-slave pair you are at risk of split-brain, you would need at least 3 master (live) brokers to enable quorum voting.

Comment: If you want one server to process all the requests and have the other 2 "in standby" then why are you creating a cluster? This is not what a cluster does. A cluster is for load-balancing through horizontal scaling. If you want servers on standby then just use HA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to connect to any node in the cluster and consume messages sent to any *other* node in the cluster then you need to set your `redistribution-delay` to something >= 0. The default `redistribution-delay` is `-1` which means messages will never be redistributed. [The documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#message-redistribution) is pretty clear about this. Here's an example configuration:

```xml
<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="#">
      <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

Also, your `message-load-balancing` *must* be `ON_DEMAND`.

Comment: Thank you @Justin ... It made things more clear .. I will change these settings and will see afect.

Comment: I have gone through all this and realized I don't need cluster. All I want is HA. If one artemis server goes down, the other one starts serving without clients knowledge. My confusion is, If I create master-slave setup on 2 machines, where master on x.x.x.41 and slave on x.x.x.42. All clients connect to 41 using ip x.x.x.41. When 41 goes down, that ip is not accessible. How clients request will be forwarded to 42. Do I need something Zoo-keeper or an extra layer may be virtual ip or something like that?

Comment: This is a completely different question than the original one you asked and not really suited to comments (which are really just meant to clarify the provided answer). I recommend you create a new question. If my answer address the original question here please mark it as correct to help other users who encounter this in the future. If the question is no longer valid then delete it.